# How to save image using opencv after done this code as shown below?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, mask

I had use otsu's method for mask the cloud. In this case, the mask is red. When I run the code, the graphs display the red mask but when i try saving it to folder , the mask turn to blue. Can anyone help what I've done wrong?

```
 def show_mask(mask, img_array, title='', mask_color=(255, 0, 0)):

            display_image = img_array.copy()
            display_image[mask != 0] = mask_color

            path1="D:Datasets/satellite2/croppedred"

            plt.imshow(display_image)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path1,img),display_image)
            #display_image.save(os.path.join(path1,img))
            plt.title(title)
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.show()  
show_mask(mask_otsu_clean, img_array, title='Otsu grayscale thresholding with morphological cleanup')
```

Comment: What is the colour order of the image? It sounds like it could be BGR rather than RGB if that is what you're seeing. Try `display_image[mask != 0] = (0,0,255)`

Comment: BGR. What happen if the order is BGR for this case?

Comment: Well when you assign the `mask_color` although you think it's overwriting the red channel, the colour channel order is reversed so you need to change the mask order

Comment: Oh you are right. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV treats the colour channel order of images by default to be BGR and not RGB this is why you see a blue colour mask.

So you need to change your mask to this

```
mask_color = (0, 0, 255)
```

then it will apply the correct colour values to the correct colour channel

Comment: oh no wonder i got the opposite color. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: oh yea okay noted. Thanks again